# Writing packages for evaluating logic in Maxima

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, maxima

I'm trying to work on some logical equivalence within Maxima and I want to write some custom packages for this. I have experimented a bit with packages in .Mac and .Lisp and so far .Mac seems to work most intuitively for me, but Lisp is probably much stronger for this use case.

For example, I tried writing an implication evaluator in both Maxima and Lisp as follows:

```lisp
(defun simp-implies (x y)
  (cond
    ((eq x nil) t)
    ((and (eq x t) (eq y t)) t)
    ((and (eq x t) (eq y nil)) nil)
    (t (list (list *implies-op* 'simp) x y))))
```

```
implies(a, b) := not a or b
```

Now when I import the .mac package I can use implies as expected, but when I use the .lisp package, simp-implies just subtracts the 'variable' implies from 'simp'. Can someone explain why, (how importing of lisp functions works in maxima) and also advise me which of the two languages would be most suitable for writing packages for Maxima? Thank you.

Comment: Have you read the documentation, and in particular the section on [Lisp and Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_37.html#SEC203)?  That would probably be a place to start.

Comment: Common Lisp is a much more extensive and, frankly, more carefully constructed language, but the Maxima language is much simpler to use for typical operations. (Historical note. The Maxima language is a simplified version of Algol; other descendants of Algol include Pascal, and, a little more distantly, C.) My advice is to try writing what you need as a Maxima program, and only fall back on CL if you encounter tasks that aren't easily handled by the Maxima language.

Comment: By the way, you can take a look at Maxima's share (i.e., add-on) package `logic` which might implement some of the functions you want.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will look into the documentation and return if I have more concrete questions :)